# Why does acetone have a lower boiling point than hexane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, intermolecular-forces

Why does acetone have a lower boiling point than hexane? I thought that since hexane is non-polar then it should have weaker intermolecular forces and a lower boiling point, but it doesn't. Why?

For reference, the boiling point of acetone is roughly 56 °C  while that of n-hexane is roughly 68 °C.

Comment: Asphalt and parafin wax are just made of nonpolar molecules, too...

Comment: Why a comparison between acetone and hexane? Why not between 2- or 3-pentanone (bp 101-102 $\ce{^{o}C}$, MW 86) and hexane (MW 86)?

Comment: The real surprise is that the smaller molecule acetone has nearly the *same* boiling point as hexane.

Answer (score 1):

Hexane is a larger, longer-chain molecule so there are more London dispersion forces between n-hexane molecule which outweighs the dipole forces in acetone.